# How to remove unwanted items in a List

Tags: java, list, jsoup

I have a List full of URLs, within that List there are many URLs I want to remove. The ones that I do want contain a specific string. Here is the code I have:

```
    String website = "www.yahoo.com";
    List<String> links = App.extractLinks(website); // this gets the links (URLs)
        for(int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
                if(links.get(i).contains("XAB")) {

                }
```

Now I know I can create a new List and do a .add(i) but that would just put in the indexes (because it is an integer) but I want to create a new List that has just the URLs I want. That is, I need a list and not a string because I need to access them one at a time in later code. There are about 80 different URLs

Comment: `newList.add(links.get(i))`?

Comment: so, new list, but add `links.get(i)` instead of `i`

Comment: Learn to use the foreach loop: `for (String url : list) { if (url.contains("XAB")) { newList.add(url); }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove items from your `List` during iteration, you can use an `Iterator`.

```
Iterator<String> iterator = links.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()) {
    // you need to invoke Iterator.next before manipulating the List
    // or any of its items
    if (!iterator.next().contains("XAB")) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

If instead, you only want to create a new `List` with the `"XAB"` `Strings`, you can use fast-enumeration:

```
List<String> myXABList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s: links) {
    if (s.contains("XAB")) {
       myXABList.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems the OP doesn't want to remove, he wants to create a new list with just the desired items

Comment: @BackSlash fixed. Had a big typo in my code. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: The rest of the URLs remain in the List. This doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 1):

```
for (Iterator i = links.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    if (!links.next().contains("XAB"))
        i.remove();
}
```

Comment: Seems the OP doesn't want to remove, he wants to create a new list with just the desired items

Comment: Well, honestly it wouldn't matter. The remove() method never works. I've tried all of this and all the the URLs remain in the List.